# jPlayer css/image not loading, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jplayer

Another newb question, much appreciation if this gets answered.

jPlayer plays, but the skin image isn't loading, and I get a

> GET http://localhost:3000/image/jplayer.blue.monday.jpg 404 (Not
>   Found)

I have the jplayer.blue.monday.scss file in apps/assets/stylesheets, and I'm loading it like @import "jplayer.blue.monday"; in application.scss, and I've tried putting the image (jplayer.blue.monday.jpg) literally everywhere.

I also tried loading it through application.html.erb head, like

```
<link type="text/css" href="/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
```

to no avail.    Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Alex Kojin, have to change `

```
"{$jplayer-images-base-url}jplayer.blue.monday.video.play.png"`
```

to

```
image-url("jplayer.blue.monday.video.play.png")
```

in the skin scss.

To be honest, not sure how you guys do this stupid shit. :)

Check out my band at soundcloud.com/whorwood, and our new site that's going to take over the internet - deadindustryradio.com